# Where should I add global listeners and change state throughtout the app in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My problem is that my App.js is not a component, its full of navigation stacks and I'm exporting them.

So how should I do it without using redux??

Comment: Can you just wrap your App in a provider component?

Comment: I’m extremely new to react native and I don’t know how to do that

Comment: To elaborate on what @Barryman9000 said, look into React Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples

Comment: @adamz4008 Thanks